# Waiting time for an ajax HTTP request

Tags: php, ajax

I am currently working on script that use ajax http request to pass the data and get response in second page.when i call the ajax function i will get response slow in total time 22.79s in which waiting time is 21.47 and receiving time is 1.32s.

Does anybody know how could i reduce the waiting time ?

Comment: Without seeing the other side of the call it's a little tough to know what's going on...

Comment: Find out why the server side process is so slow, nothing to do with ajax really...

Comment: What do you mean by getting response in second page. Ajax is supposed to be async connect on one page afaik

Comment: With such limited information I can only assume that the process you are invoking serverside is one that requires processing.  Without knowledge of this code it is hard to say how to improve it.  Or it may be just latency, but that is not as likely with the receiving time being so much less.

Answer (score 5):

Waiting time is a time of your server side script execution. You should improve your PHP script to make it work faster.

Take a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - there you can post you code for peer review and ask people help you to improve its performance.

Also, you can take some PHP profiler and see what piece of code is slow by yourself. I were using XDebug for that: http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler. Very helpful tool.

Comment: i have passed 207.2 KB data is that reason?

Comment: Reason is in your PHP script. It is slow. 207.KB should not be a problem by itself. But how you process it in PHP - could be and I think IS a real reason for it to be slow

Comment: thanx FAngel i wiil check my php code with tool u suggested me.

Comment: @NaitikMistry If you are on windows, [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/) tool will be helpful for viewing profiler logs

Comment: One more Question FAngel this code is working perfectly fine and quick on my devlopment server . only on live server the response is slow?

Comment: Hard to say. 22 seconds - that is really long. Maybe you have some not optimized DB query which works fast on dev server with small amount of data (and a single connection), but is slow on live site where you have more data (and many users?). Maybe something else. Without code and any additional info it is impossible to say what is causing your problem. The best for you would be to learn how to use XDebug and profile your code.